# Is there a way to get rid of the TextInput 'Select all' popup?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

On Android, when you do a long touch on a TextInput widget, a 'Select All    Paste' popup shows up. Is there a way to disable this feature ?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in the source code of TextInput. Simply set the TextInput use_bubble to False to disable the selection paste popup.

Answer (score 0):

yes the kivy text input has a property `use_bubble`, change it to False if you don't want this behaviour